# sorted Binary Tree, stuck with loop (recursion)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
private void createSortedBT2(int index, BinaryTree<Country> cNode){
    if(index >= 0){
        if(db.getCountry(index).isLess(cNode.getContent())){
            if(cNode.getLeftTree().isEmpty()){
                cNode.getLeftTree().setContent(db.getCountry(index));
            }else{
                createSortedBT2(index, cNode.getLeftTree());
            }
        }else if(db.getCountry(index).isGreater(cNode.getContent())){
            if(cNode.getRightTree().isEmpty()){
                cNode.getRightTree().setContent(db.getCountry(index));
            }else{
                createSortedBT2(index, cNode.getRightTree());
            }
        }
        createSortedBT2(index-1, bt);
    }
}
```

Hi, i wanted to know why this method is stuck in a loop. Im using an IDE where i can inspect the BinaryTree and everything in its correct position, but its stuck somehow. It doesnt show any stackoverflow or nullpointerexceptions aswell. index is initialized with 18 and cNode with an empty root (db is an array, and all methods work).  (I know that the tree is unbalanced but this was the task we were supposed to do anyway).

Comment: Hint: what happens if you add a `cNode` that's already in the tree?

Comment: I dont think that creates any problems since cNode gives me the position in the tree, and  is initialized with the root at the beginnning, after that it just starts comparing and inserting at the right  position